# Type 'void' is not assignable to type in Chip Material

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My idea it's to pass a function from Parent to child in the another COmponent.

The parent has this function:

```
  const handleDelete = (id : number) => {
     console.log(id)
  };
```

The child has the code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the props of the `onDelete` on the child. It seems like it might be a void method.

The right way to call it in this case is like this, assuming row.id is provided by the parent somewhere:

```js
onDelete={()=>handleDelete(row.id)}
```

If the row id, is coming from the child, then you're allowed to do either:

```js
onDelete={(rowId)=>handleDelete(rowId)}
```

```js
onDelete={handleDelete}
```

Because then the type signature would match

Comment: I'm doing a loop inside the Child component, so will be from the row.id

Comment: Check the comments from the compiler tsx please

Comment: Ravi L's solution should fix the issue. Do you mean the compiler still gives the same warning?

Comment: i have the same warning

Comment: @tuomokar Type 'void' is not assignable to type '(event: any) => void'

Comment: Then you either didn't do what Ravi L suggested, or your editor is stuck (try rebooting it). Your issue at the moment comes because you're trying to pass the result of the function to the prop, instead of passing the function itself. But like Ravi L, suggested, `onDelete={()=>handleDelete(row.id)}` fixes it so that you pass a function instead of its result.

Comment: Also do note that you have the same issue with the `onClick` prop, so that might actually be why you're still having the same compiler warning.